# Remote inspection for iOS Books

Tags: ios, books, web-inspector

I can inspect an ePub book in Books on Mac using Safari’s web inspector. I can also inspect a web page in iOS Safari when the phone is plugged in to my mac using desktop Safari’s web inspector.

What I don’t seem to be able to do though is debug iOS Books remotely using desktop Safari’s web inspector.

Given that I’ve got an issue that’s only occurring in iOS Books and not in Mac Books, this is rather annoying. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Run the ePub through the open source Calibre eBook software, convert it to something else and back to ePub format and then test.  It might fix the glitch in the formatting.

Comment: This is a recurring problem with any book built using my project’s ebook scripts. Specifically here I know what the bug is from building multiple variants of multiple books to test, but that involves blind debugging by uploading test versions of the books. Trying to fix this bug rather than removing functionality is going to be a lot quicker though with real-time debugging and manipulation of the book’s source (something that’s possible on mac Books).

Comment: I agree but I don’t see any viable solution. Except maybe running Xcode and an iOS simulator on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only connect the Web Inspector to an iOS app with the get-task-allow entitlement, so you can't connect the inspector to an app you're not able to debug.

If your iOS device is jailbroken, you can install [**inspectorplus**](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/li.oldman.inspectorplus/) which allows you to connect the Web Inspector to any web view in any app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK, that looks pretty conclusive, thanks for the technical explanation.